# LDA - Recognition Pattern in Python (sklearn)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda

I am trying to execute this code on Python. This code refers to a LDA, from sklearn.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.lda import LDA

X = np.array ([0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.001550, 
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.201550, 0.011111, 0.077778,
               0.011111, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.092732, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.035659, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.066667, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.010853,
               0.000000, 0.033333, 0.055556, 0.055556, 0.077778, 
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.268170, 0.000000, 
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.130233, 0.000000, 
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.034109, 0.077778, 0.055556, 0.011111, 
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.155388, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.181395, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.001550, 0.007752, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.011111, 0.088889, 0.033333,
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.142857, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.093023, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.009302, 0.010853, 
               0.000000, 0.100000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.022222, 0.088889, 0.033333, 0.238095,
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.032558,
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.182946, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.022222, 0.077778, 0.055556,
               0.000000, 0.102757])

y = np.array ([0.000000, 0.000000, 0.008821, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.179631, 0.010471, 0.036649,
               0.026178, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.020942, 0.010471,
               0.000000, 0.109215, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.060144, 
               0.000000, 0.042502, 0.000000, 0.005613, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.018444, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.013633,
               0.020942, 0.031414, 0.083770, 0.015707, 0.041885,
               0.041885, 0.057592, 0.010471, 0.233788, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.018444, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.090617, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.104250, 0.005236, 0.020942, 0.031414,
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.010471, 0.015707, 0.005236,
               0.056314, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.026464, 0.000000,
               0.004010, 0.000000, 0.031275, 0.007217, 0.036889,
               0.007217, 0.013633, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.005236,
               0.047120, 0.057592, 0.015707, 0.010471, 0.047120,
               0.062827, 0.005236, 0.262799, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000802, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.001604, 0.000000, 0.052927, 0.000000,
               0.039294, 0.026178, 0.041885, 0.031414, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.041885, 0.073298, 0.000000, 0.308874,
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.236568, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
               0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.020942, 0.015707,
               0.000000, 0.029010])
```

> clf = LDA()
>   clf.fit(X,y)
>   print(clf.predict([0, 2]))

And show me this error message:

```
clf.fit(X, y)
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

What I do to fix it? I could not find this solution on documentation.

Comment: what are you trying to do with:
`clf = LDA() clf.fit(X, y) LDA(n_components=None, priors=None)`?

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake, the right one is:
clf = LDA()
clf.fit(X,y)
print(clf.predict([0, 2]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is one dimensional. when you do:

```
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
```

X.shape is not a matrix of samples and feautures but an array of shape (106,). You need more than one sample. As is, You have a bunch of features and one sample. A matrix of 4 samples with 4 features would be defined as:

```
featureMat = np.array([[ 10, 30, 40, 50],
                       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
                       [ 54, 75, 6,  56],
                       [ 65, 34, 23, 22]])
```

So featureMat.shape would be (4,4).

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t understand you. What I need do in my code to fix the error? thank you!

Comment: You need more dimensions to your array. The reason why your error occurs is because your array is shape (106,). Add more dimensions to your array if you don't want this error. In other words, you need an array of arrays, not a simple array.

Comment: Ok, I added 2 dimensiosn in my array. But I got the error message ValueError: bad input shape (2, 132)
What does it mean?

Comment: It means that your samples and target dimensions are incompatible. X needs to be n_samples by n_features and Y needs to be an n_sample array.

Comment: There are situations when you have a one-dimensional problem, so I don't think it is a good idea to have the feature vector be constrained to multiple dimensions..